# React/JavaScript: Adding property to nested array in state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to add an id number to the nested array in data called action.  The code I'm using is:

```
const { data } = this.state
        const newData = Object.assign([...data.action], Object.assign([...data.action],{0:'id' }))
```

but this code is not working. The result I am looking for is: 
{id:1 action: "user...}

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the spread operator.

```
const newData = {
  ...data,
  action: {
    ...data.action,
    id: 1
  }
};
```

If action is an array, you can try something like this:

```
const newAction = data.action.map((actionItem, index) => ({
  ...actionItem,
  id: index + 1
}));
const newData = {
  ...data,
  action: newAction
};
```

Comment: How do I make id add +1 for each item in the array?

Comment: This was helpful but I need id inside the array objects that inside action.

Comment: Now it says id: NaN

Comment: Maybe, it is undefined. Try `id: typeof actionItem.id === 'undefined' ? 1 : actionItem.id + 1`

Comment: And I need it to be the first property in the array.

Comment: They all say 1 instead of incrementing. Each id should be unique.

Comment: Which answer? Because this was working but they all say 1` id: typeof actionItem.id === 'undefined' ? 1 : actionItem.id + 1`

Comment: Use index of map function

Comment: Numbers are incrementing now but I need id to be the first property. Right now it is the second.

Comment: Don't be ridiculous, help yourself, learn/search if it is a difference. And again, don't ask the same Q every few hours.